# Visibility ON/OFF in the BGE via Python

Tags: python, game-engine, visibility

I'm trying to make a simple Asteroid game with the BGE, using Python when necessary. I want to make 'visible' the ship trails when I press 'W' to increase the speed and make them 'invisible' if 'W' is not pressed. Where is the error? I'm very new with Python scripts. [image: see the screen shot]

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
own['trails'] = trailsObject
own['trails'].visible = True
own['trails'].visible = False
```

or as i can see in the image:

```
cont.activate(trails) # to activate the actuator
cont.deactivate(trails) # to deactivate the actuator
```

Also visit the [BGE Documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78_release/contents.html).

**Next time please take a moment to copy your code as text and format it**.

Answer (score 1):

You should have `own.setVisible` not `setVisibility`.

```
import bge

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner
wKey = cont.sensors['wKey']

if wKey.positive:
    own.setVisible(True)
else:
    own.setVisible(False)
```

That way you don't need the visibility actuator.